# CSS, Javascript and Images have zero length

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-7

I'm trying to port an ASP.NET MVC 1.0 / Visual Studio 2008 project to ASP.NET MVC RC 2 / Visual Studio 2010. The project is (and has always been) running on IIS 7.

Dynamic content (everything that's being delivered by controllers) works fine, but static content such as CSS / Javascript / Images gives me a "200 OK" response, a Content-Length of 0 and no content. It's as if all those files were entirely empty (I made sure the files are not empty though).

The static content is in a directory that I excluded from ASP.NET routing via IgnoreRoute.

It can't be a hidden 404 error since adding some garbage characters to the URL produces a reguar 404 error.

It doesn't seem to be related to filesystem permissions since I've already given everyone full access rights in the contents directory.

What could possibly be the problem?

**Edit:** I just created a completely new ASP.NET MVC website from scratch and tried running that in IIS. It has exactly the same problem! So it's not really a problem of converting my project to MVC2 at all, it rather seems to be IIS that's causing the trouble. But what could possibly be the problem?

Comment: Can you post your `web.config` or possibly give us an external url we can see?

Comment: The problem does not seem to be related to this specific project at all. See my edit above.

Comment: You shouldn't need to Ignore the directory for the static content - it kinda should just be clever enough to display it. Have you tried without the extra ignore rule in it and if that works?

Comment: As described in the edit, this problem is not at all related to my project. It even occurs with a brandnew asp.net mvc project, no changes applied. So the fault must be somewhere in the IIS configuration

Answer (score 21):

As I just found out, the problem was that Control Panel -> Windows Features -> World Wide Web Services - > Common HTTP Features -> Static Content was not checked. Once I checked this, everything worked fine again.

Comment: +1 for providing the answer, and for `Commong` because I was afraid I was the only one who ever made that typo.

Comment: On Windows 10 is  Control Panel -> Programs -> Turn Windows Features on and off -> Internet Information Services -> World Wide Web Services -> Common HTTP Features -> Static Content